# Перебор запроса

Tags: php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    print_r($row);
};
```

Имеется 3 ряда по 2 значения, каким образом можно сохранить значения каждого цикла при переборе?
`print_r` выводит следующее:

```
Array ( [id] => 0 [price] => 8000 ) 
Array ( [id] => 1 [price] => 100 ) 
Array ( [id] => 2 [price] => 500 )
```

Comment: А что за переменная `$row_upsell`? И что вы понимаете под "_сохранить значения каждого цикла при переборе_"?

Comment: Куда сохранить? в базу данных?

Comment: Сохранить в массив, как мне обращаться к разным id? например: echo $row[id][0]; на экране пустота

Answer (score 3):

записываете в массив и извлекаете по ключам

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[$row['id']] = $row['price'];
};

echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];
echo $array[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Советую прочитать книгу по PHP или посмотреть минимальные видео лекции. В вашем цикле функция `mysql_fetch_assoc()` возвращает ассоциативный массив, соответственно в каждой итерации у вас в переменно `$row` лежит массив, где ключами являются поля из БД. Если вам нужно в дальнейшем обращаться записи БД по id, то используйте хеш таблицу, где уникальный ключ (id) будет выступать в роли хеша

```
$products = array(); // будующий массив с товарами
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $products[$row['id']] = $row; // кладем в массив все поля из БД по ключу ID
};
echo $products[1]['price']; // выводит поле price из БД c ID товара 1
```

### Дополнение

Из комментария

> например: echo $row[id][0]; на экране пустота –  Игорь Волков

Если в цикле, то просто обращаемся к элементу по ключу `echo $row['id'];`. Ключ это строка, так что обязательно в кавычках